# jquery after() function is not adding HTML in the right place

Tags: jquery, ajax

to everyone..
i have a web page where i have a list of wall-posts rendered from mysql-DB
and also an textarea field to publish a new post..
after pressing the submit button the ajax function is called and a new post must appear above the old once..
in jquery function that i am using `after()` build-in function..

```
function wallPostSend(a, b) {
    var url = "scripts/functions.php";
    var randomNum = "<?php echo $randomNum; ?>";
    var contentWall = $('#news_text').val();
    $(".small_loader").show();
    $.post(url, {
        request: "wallPostSend",
        mem1: a,
        mem2: b,
        content: contentWall,
        security: randomNum
    }, function(data) {
        $(".small_loader").hide();
        $(".after_this").after().html(data).slideDown();
        ---this part is the problem..
        $('#news_text').val("type here..........").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

`$(".after_this")` - refers to a div that looks like this:

```
    <div class="after_this"></div>
```

I need a new post to appear here. For example

```
<table>post 11</table>
<table>post 10</table>post that is already from DATABASE
<table>post 9</table>post that is already from DATABASE
<table>post 8</table>post that is already from DATABASE
<table>post 7</table>post that is already from DATABASE
<table>post 6</table>post that is already from DATABASE
<table>post N</table>post that is already from DATABASE
```

AJAX respond is `<?php echo '<table>post text..blah blah</table>' ?>` a new table with a new post that I want to appear before  post 10 which is the first post in the HTML code.

Then if another post is posted it must appear again first in the list without overwriting any of the previous posts.

Comment: I think you must use prepend() or append() to add it to the div and not after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it this way:

```
 $(".after_this").after(data).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `content` that needs to be passed in as arguments

[.after(content)](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
 $(".after_this").after(data).slideDown();
```